# Execute command substitutions in input read from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In shell script how to make script read commands in input file string

## Example 1 (script1.sh):

```
a="google.analytics.account.id=`read a`"
echo $a
```

## Example 2 (script2.sh):

cat script2.sh

```
a=`head -1 input.txt`
echo $a
```

---

## Sample `input.txt`

```
google.analytics.account.id=`read a`
```

---

If I run `script1.sh` the `read` command is working fine, but when I am running `script2.sh`, the `read` command is not executed, but is printed as part of the output.

So I want script2.sh to have the same output as script1.sh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy's answer solves your problem, but I think you meant to use this in your code instead: `a="google.analytics.account.id=$(IFS= read -r id; echo "$id")"`.

Comment: Good point. Running `read a` in a subshell will never change the value of the variable `a` in the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your `input.txt` contents are effectively executed as a script here; **only do this if you entirely trust those contents to run arbitrary commands on your machine**. That said:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- not /bin/sh; needed for $'' and $(<...) syntax.

# generate a random sigil that's unlikely to exist inside your script.txt
# maybe even sigil="EOF-$(uuidgen)" if you're guaranteed to have it.
sigil="EOF-025CAF93-9479-4EDE-97D9-483A3D5472F3"

# generate a shell script which includes your input file as a heredoc
script="cat <<$sigil"$'\n'"$(<input.txt)"$'\n'"$sigil"

# run that script
eval "$script"
```

Comment: I don't see the point of `$script` here. Seems to me like a long way to do: `script="cat input.txt"`. And isn't OP just trying to execute the first line of `input.txt` and put it into variable `$a`? `a=$(source <(head -n 1 input.txt))` might do the trick.
`

Comment: @PesaThe, this is not at all `script="cat input.txt"`. Try executing it and inspecting the values in practice, keeping in mind that heredocs with unquoted sigils do the parts of shell parsing that are generally desirable when expanding templates (command substitution, variables) but leave out the things that are surprising (glob expressions, string-splitting, etc).

Comment: @PesaThe, ...for that matter, see the `sh`-compliant equivalent given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In script1.sh the first line is evaluated, therefore the `read a` is executed and replaced in the string.

In script 2.sh the first line is evaluated, therefore the resulting string from execution of `head` is put into the variable a.

There is no re-evaluation done on the resulting string. If you add the evaluation with `eval $a` and the first line in input.txt is exactly as the first line of script1.sh (actually the `a="..."` is missing) then you might get the same result. The heredoc, as CharlesDuffy suggested, seems more accurate.

Comment: using eval $a in script2.sh worked                Thanks a lot to all